# Abandoning Blue Card Visa - Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card

I would like to know if there is any problem if I give up from a position in Germany after I received the Visa that allows the Blue Card application. I am still in my country, but due to some personal issues, I am considering giving up from the position and stay in my country.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The government should have zero problems that you did not visit. The visa can expire on your passport without you having to do anything.

You should inform your company/employer that you will not be joining if you don't want a bad reputation in case you want to join again.